# How to pass inner ref and use it inside a HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have the input component, and a wrapper component called `FancyInput`.

I want to forward the inner `Input` ref through `FancyInput`, and also use the same ref inside the `FancyInput`, like calling `ref.focus.`

##### edit:

```
const SomeComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const textInputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null)

    // how should I use textInputRef here, and also 
    // pass the ref to the FancyInput?

    return (
        <View>
           <FancyInput ref={textInputRef} />
       </View>
    )
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use forwardRef() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664209/how-can-i-use-forwardref-in-react)

Comment: @Benjamin no, i want to use the inner ref inside the HOC too, not just pass it through

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your component in [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

Here is a minimal code snippet.

```js
const FancyInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <TextInput ref={ref}></TextInput>
})
```

Suppose that we use it in a different component. Here is an example.

```js
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
    const textInputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null)

    return (
        <View>
           <FancyInput ref={textInputRef} />
       </View>
    )
}
```

You can use the `ref` as usual in `SomeComponent` to call certain functions for the `TextInput` in `FancyInput`. The workflow is the same for other components.

Comment: I add another example base on your, to clarify my question

Comment: Just use it as usual?

Comment: I mean I want to use the `ref` inside the `FancyInput`, I want to manipulate the ref functionality

Comment: You can. We have just passed it as a prop. In `FancyInput` you can use it via the `ref` prop.